# How can a 74LS76 JK Flip Flop's outputs Q and Q-bar not be fully complementary?

Tags: flipflop, counter

I have a 74LS76 JK flip flop hooked up as follows:

[image]

You think that should be easy. But look at my scope traces of Q above and Q-bar below:

[image]

how the heck can a JK flip flop's output Q and Q-bar be not completely complementary?

Here is Q above against the CLK below if it helps figuring that one out.

[image]

Even if this is falling edge triggered, this should not happen!

Clock is 4 MHz.

**More scope traces requested in comments:**

Here is both probes in Q:

[image]

here is !Q against CLK:
[image]

Q against (Q AND !Q)  (AND - 74HC08)
[image]

!Q against (Q AND !Q)
[image]

CLK against (Q AND !Q)
[image]

So you can see, this is real, not an issue with the scope. It's also a fairly isolated test so not much could go wrong. The wiring checked and double checked.

1. pin 1 = CLK
2. pin 2 = H
3. pin 3 = H
4. pin 4 = H
5. pin 5 = H (Vcc)
6. pin 6 = pin 1
7. pin 7 = H
8. pin 8 = pin 3
9. pin 9 = pin12
10. pin 10 = NC (2Q)
11. pin 11 = NC (2!Q)
12. pin 12 = RCO of 74LS161 #2 - or H for same test on JK FF #2 of same chip
13. pin 13 = GND (L)
14. pin 14 = NC (1!Q)
15. pin 15 = NC (1Q)
16. pin 16 = H

bypass cap 100nF riding between pin 5 and 13

This is read from the wiring, not from the schematics.

Here is the chip, I am in Brazil, and so I'm stuck with what I'm getting here.

[image]

I don't think that ground bounces are the issue since I check my power rails with the scope too and it is just too reproducible with this chip.

**UPDATE:**

I would have to get another '76, which I will try. Meanwhile I tried the '74 and it is almost working with that, except the high stage that is supposed to toggle when the ripple-carry-output of the '161 is high and the next clock pulse comes, that isn't working right. It would toggle too early. I had to make a poor man's AND gate with resistor diode and that would mess things up anyway. If I use a real AND gate then I'm going to have switching delays again.

I guess I haven't paid attention to that previously, I need to trigger that on the falling edge of the RCO, so maybe I need to get a falling edge triggered JK ff anyway. Let's figure this out:

- 74LS76 - DUAL J-K FLIP-FLOPS WITH PRESET AND CLEAR
- 74LS78 - DUAL J-K FLIP-FLOPS WITH PRESET, COMMON CLOCK, AND COMMON
  CLEAR
- 74LS112 - DUAL NEGATIVE EDGE TRIGGERED J-K FLIP-FLOPS WITH
  PRESET AND CLEAR

I'll run now before the store closes here.

**BACKGROUND ONLY:** I have a 16-bit counter, 74LS161, it runs at 4 MHz now but I want to get it to work with 16 MHz. The counter value becomes RAM addresses, and for that application I found that glitching is a major problem. So I moved from async 74LS393 with 74HC4040 to 4 74LS161 counters.

For the correct derivation / switching of the counter values to become the RAM addresses, I require bit 0 (LSB of low byte) and bit 8 (LSB of high byte) to exist in both straight and inverted form. But, if I use an inverter to invert this bit, then the follow-up address selection logic glitches because of the delay of the inverted LSB.

I thought I had a solution by running the LSB as a parallel JK flip flop which would be clocked by the same clock, or an prior inverted clock, depending on whether the JK ff is rising vs. falling edge triggered. Here is a piece of the schematics using the 74LS78 JK flip flops:

[image]

sorry for the vertical arrangement and low resolution. Anyway, right now what matters is just the JK flip flop.

If I use the 74LS78 I have it glitching on the high stage, in such a way that Q and Q-bar flip over even just by me putting the scope probe in one or the other, and if both are tied as inputs to the following AND gate(s), they end up rapidly flipping around.

Now I gave up on the 74LS78 and used the '76 instead. With the problem as initially stated.

Comment: Just spending one minute on this, so far, I can see that the absolute maximum specification (and I would under no circumstances try it) is \$25\:\text{MHz}\$ for the clock input. This is assuming there's only \$15\:\text{pF}\$, the temperature is room temp, low impedance drive, and the supply voltage is \$5.5\:\text{V}\$. That goes down to \$20\:\text{MHz}\$ at \$50\:\text{pF}\$. It wouldn't take much to push you below your goal. Just want to make sure the rest is right before looking over your details here. Can you let us know?

Comment: @jonk, this is currently clocked at only 4 MHz.

Comment: I also simplified the question to the one main issue I found with one chip. Better focus.

Comment: Is the scope trigger set to alternate, or chop? Can you try a D flip flop instead (eg. 74LS74)?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, this time I don't think it's an issue with my scope, it triggers on channel 1 (above, Q) and channel 2 just follows. For any other comparison of CLK and !CLK or other such things there was no phase shift like that observed.

Comment: If there is crosstalk in the trigger circuit the point on the waveform where it triggers may vary depending on which channel is displayed. Can you show us /Q vs clock? I see the 74LS76 has an unusual pinout. Are you sure it is wired correctly? On the main schematic J, K, and /S appear to be floating.

Comment: I can take more pictures tomorrow, but !Q vs. CLK, you can simply overlay the scope photos, as nothing changes. It's totally stable. And the main schematic doesn't matter right now as I'm testing the '76 in isolation. I have verified that both flip flops behave the same way on the 4 MHz clock and also on a 2 MHz clock. If I drive the J and K from a RCO of the '161 then the Q and !Q are both complementary, although since it is 16 times slower than the original clock, I cannot guarantee that there isn't exactly one half of a clock cycle difference between the two, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: To eliminate the question of skew to/in the scope, you could tie Q and !Q together with a spare AND/OR/XOR gate and scope its output. Also, what is your clock source? Is it low impedance enough? If not sure, maybe you could buffer it? (Just guessing here, looking for unusual issues)

Comment: @GuntherSchadow:  Set your scope to "chop" instead of "alt."   You have an analog oscilloscope with a single electron gun.  To display two traces, it has to simulate two guns.  It has two methods to do that.  "Alt" means that it shows each trace on every second sweep.  You **cannot** view synchronized signals that way - there will always be a time shift between channels.  "Chop" shows both traces in one sweep so that they are synchronized, but it switches back and forth between the two rapidly in one sweep. Youcan see synchronized events but you lose bandwidth.

Comment: Connect both probes to Q. See if you still get an offset. Switch between "alt" and "chop" and see if the offset goes away.

Comment: No, that's really not it. There is no issue with the two channels, the issue is real. I am going to add all the other requested pictures now...

Comment: see updates to verify for yourselves

Comment: @BruceAbbott Now I will swap in the '74 D flip flop instead. Fingers crossed and this will suit my need. However, the question about the JK ff still stands. I would think it should be reproducible and many just be about how these '76 chips are designed. If anyone has them on hand, I'd appreciate if they might show it.

BTW even if I go down to 400 kHz, 200 kHZ and lower, I see the exact same logic behavior.  Very surprising to me, perhaps its a known fact. But I never thought a JK ff is supposed to have Q = !Q during the CLK high when toggling.,

Comment: Your scope traces show that the 74LS76 /Q output is indeed toggling on positive edges, which should not happen. I can think of only 2 possibilities - 1. ground bounce on clock input is upsetting the latch. 2. it isn't a 74LS76, or is a variant that doesn't toggle correctly with J and K high. Can you show us a photo of the chip? Where did you get it from? https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/sequential/seq_2.html

Comment: @BruceAbbott, I updated the question again, adding a picture of the chip and more info.

Comment: _"I tried the '74 and it is almost working with that, except the high stage that is supposed to toggle when the ripple-carry-output of the '161 is high and the next clock pulse comes, that isn't working right."_ - So the LS74 is toggling and correctly and producing complementary outputs? Perhaps your LS76 is faulty. Anyway I think your design is overly complex and too dependent on critical timing. A good design would not be sensitive to momentary glitches on the address lines during the transition from one address to the next.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, what would be a better design if I have a counter that generates RAM addresses? Use address latches? And the control of those address latches is what I need these well timed signals for. I will write this up in an article and you will get honorable mention there anyway for your BJT inverting level shifter, I send you a pre-print for your critical review. Thank you!

Comment: Without seeing the entire design and understanding what it is supposed to do I can't make any recommendations. However you seem to be using both edges of the clock and have critical timing issues, which suggests a poor design. Is there a forum where we can discuss it? (perhaps  [https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this was a bad chip! It functioned almost perfectly fine, no issues except the switching was not right. I went and bought another one for an eff-ton of money 4 USD -- twice the price of a kilo of strawberries -- and behold:

[image]

Note how much more smooth the traces are. Not that it would necessarily matter, but clearly it behaves differently than the first chip.

This new one is also a TI make, but looks nicer. Not sure if the other one was a Chinese fake?

[image]